# JET SQL: Join two tables on different columns of each table which I had to use string manipulation to achieve the same format for comparison

Tags: sql, database

```
TABLE dbo_R5PERSONNEL
column PER_DESC
Do, John 
Jones, Jacky

TABLE dbo_R5USERS
column USR_DESC
John Do
Jack Jones
```

Q: How would I join these two tables to get all the USR_DESC from Table dbo_R5USERS that exist in column PER_DESC in Table dbo_R5PERSONNEL.

I used string manipulation to capitalize and extract just the last names from each table

```
SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC),  INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' ') + 1, LEN(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC)) - INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' '))) AS LastName
FROM dbo_R5USERS
WHERE dbo_R5USERS.USR_ACTIVE = '+'
ORDER BY dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC;


SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),1,INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),',')-1)) AS LastName
FROM dbo_R5PERSONNEL
WHERE dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_NOTUSED='+'
ORDER BY dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC;
```

How would I incorporate a JOIN on these two subqueries? Is there another method to achieve my desired results?

Thanks in advance!

Update 1:

```
SELECT R.LastName
    , P.LastName FROM 
(
    SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC)
        , INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' ') + 1, LEN(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC)) - INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' '))) AS LastName 
    FROM dbo_R5USERS 
    WHERE dbo_R5USERS.USR_ACTIVE = '+'
) R 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),1,INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),‌​',')-1)) AS LastName 
    FROM dbo_R5PERSONNEL 
    WHERE dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_NOTUSED='+'
) P 
    ON R.LastName = P.LastName
```

Comment: You should just be able to join the computed columns.  Try something and post code that does/doesn't work.  That being said...you gotta fix that schema.

Comment: Hi Norla,This is what I came up with but it produces an error:Syntax error in JOIN operation.  SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' ') + 1, LEN(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC)) - INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' '))) AS LastName FROM dbo_R5USERS INNER JOIN (SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),1,INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),',')-1)) AS LastName FROM dbo_R5PERSONNEL WHERE dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_NOTUSED='+') ON (dbo_R5USERS.LastName = dbo_R5PERSONNEL.LastName) WHERE dbo_R5USERS.USR_ACTIVE = '+'.

Comment: Please edit post and put code in code tags.

Comment: Hi Norla,This is what I came up with but it produces an error:Syntax error in JOIN operation. `SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' ') + 1, LEN(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC)) - INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' '))) AS LastName FROM dbo_R5USERS INNER JOIN (SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),1,INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),‌​',')-1)) AS LastName FROM dbo_R5PERSONNEL WHERE dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_NOTUSED='+') ON (dbo_R5USERS.LastName = dbo_R5PERSONNEL.LastName) WHERE dbo_R5USERS.USR_ACTIVE = '+'`

Comment: I also tried the following code but got an error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. That is odd because when I run the 2 select statements individually, it works.

Comment: `SELECT R.LastName, P.LastName
FROM
(SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC),  INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' ') + 1, LEN(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC)) - INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5USERS.USR_DESC), ' '))) AS LastName
FROM dbo_R5USERS
WHERE dbo_R5USERS.USR_ACTIVE = '+') R INNER JOIN 
( SELECT UCASE(MID(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),1,INSTR(TRIM(dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_DESC),',')-1)) AS LastName
FROM dbo_R5PERSONNEL
WHERE dbo_R5PERSONNEL.PER_NOTUSED='+') P
ON R.LastName = P.LastName`

Comment: Waiting for peer review, but I added your code into the question.